# What is the maximum number of CNAME records per hosted zone in Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

There is a mixed information on the internet about the number of CNAME records that can be defined for a domain. Some say that there is no limit and millions of CNAME records can be created. Others say that it depends on a provider that can enforce limits.

I can't find exact answer about AWS Route 53 limits. Will Route 53 support 200K+ CNAME records per hosted zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits are not expressed directly in number of subdomains or cnames, but rather in number of records and hosted zones, among other things.

Therefore, there is 10,000 records per hosted zone, but it can be increased. Also you can have 500 hosted zones per account.

Comment: This answer is a copy of @Marcin's answer. Therefore this question should be marked a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62927948/8016720

Answer (score -1):

If you are new then max to max you can create 20 Cname in Rout-53
If you have existing account then your account have by defaults can create 50 Cname In Rout-53

Comment: This is not true. I have just added 60 CNAMES to a hosted zone and all is OK. You should check the information before posting.

Comment: @realPro If you disagree with a question, use the voting buttons. If you continue to insult people on this forum, I will recommend your account for moderation and suspension.